# In what sense is the death of Jesus considered a sacred event in religious beliefs?

Tags: jesus

John 16:2 New International Version

> They will put you out of the synagogue; in fact, the time is coming when anyone who kills you will think they are offering a **service** to God.

Jesus was addressing the listeners, but it can also be applied to Him. In what way was the death of Jesus a act of worship (**latreia**) to God?

Comment: I am struggling to understand the question.  "latreia" is always a service to God and Jesus' work/sacrifice was never described this way.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

> 38 Then saith he unto them, My soul is exceeding sorrowful, even unto
> death: tarry ye here, and watch with me.
>
> 39 And he went a little further, and fell on his face, and prayed,
> saying, O my Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass from me:
> nevertheless not as I will, but as thou wilt. (Matthew 26:38-39)

Jesus' suffering & death were an act of complete submission to His Father's will. He worshipped, reverenced, and obeyed His Father by allowing His actions to be directed by His Father's will, even when it was the most excruciating option available.

> I have glorified thee on the earth: I have finished the work which thou gavest me to do. (John 17:4)

> After this, Jesus knowing that all things were now accomplished...he said, It is finished: and he bowed his head, and gave up the ghost. (John 19:28-30)

His sacrifice was the greatest act of discipleship.

Comment: Did the Jews know that crucifixion was an act of latreia?

Comment: @Betho's I suspect few (if any) present appreciated the magnitude of what was happening.

Comment: The evildoer on the cross: "This one did nothing" and "when You enter Your kingdom". Is there any possibility that he could have reached the idea that Jesus was a sacrifice of worship to God?

Answer (score 1):

Title question doesn't match the body. This answer addresses the body, not the title.

John 16:2 is about people who **mistakenly** think they are serving God while condemning the Disciples to death. See the immediate context in 15:18-16:3.

(New Revised Standard Version)

> If the world hates you, be aware that it hated me before it hated you.
> If you belonged to the world, the world would love you as its own.
> Because you do not belong to the world, but I have chosen you out of
> the world—therefore the world hates you. Remember the word that I said
> to you, ‘Servants are not greater than their master.’ If they
> persecuted me, they will persecute you; if they kept my word, they
> will keep yours also. But they will do all these things to you on
> account of my name, because they do not know him who sent me. If I had
> not come and spoken to them, they would not have sin; but now they
> have no excuse for their sin. Whoever hates me hates my Father also.
> If I had not done among them the works that no one else did, they
> would not have sin. But now they have seen and hated both me and my
> Father. It was to fulfill the word that is written in their law, ‘They
> hated me without a cause.’
>
> “I have said these things to you to keep you from stumbling. They will
> put you out of the synagogues. Indeed, an hour is coming when those
> who kill you will think that by doing so they are offering worship to
> God. And they will do this because they have not known the Father or
> me.

Whether John 16:2 is intended to be about Jesus or not, those who killed Jesus did claim that they were doing so to fulfil the Jewish moral law. See John 19:5-7

> Pilate said to [the Jewish authorites], “Here is the man!” When the
> chief priests and the police saw him, they shouted, “Crucify him!
> Crucify him!” Pilate said to them, “Take him yourselves and crucify
> him; I find no case against him.” The Jews answered him, “We have a
> law, and according to that law he ought to die because he has claimed
> to be the Son of God.”

Likewise Matthew 26:57-67

> Those who had arrested Jesus took him to Caiaphas the high priest,
> in whose house the scribes and the elders had gathered. [...] Then the high
> priest said to him, “I put you under oath before the living God, tell
> us if you are the Messiah, the Son of God.”
>
> Jesus said to him, “You have said so. But I tell you, From now on you will see the Son of Man
> seated at the right hand of Power and coming on the clouds of heaven.”
>
> Then the high priest tore his clothes and said, “He has blasphemed!
> Why do we still need witnesses? You have now heard his blasphemy. What
> is your verdict?” They answered, “He deserves death.”

Comment: Was every blasphemy conviction an act of latreia?

Comment: @Betho's Not worship of God, certainly, since they were done by people who "hated both me and my Father". Hence how they only *think* they are offering worship to God. So not the same meaning of *latreia/latria* as the (much more recent) theological term, if that's what you're asking about.